# How can I remove lines from .txt files using a loop?

Tags: file, bash, loops, edit

In my current directory I have a couple of .txt files. I want to write a script to search for a  string in those .txt files, and delete lines which contains that string.
For example, I'd like to delete all lines which have the word "start" in all .txt files in my current directory.

I have written the following code, but I don't know how to continue!

```
#!bin\bash
files=`find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt`
```

How should I use "while" to go through each file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use Globs to Populate Loop Variables

When you use `-maxdepth 1` on the current directory, you aren't recursing into subdirectories. If that's the case, there's no need at all to use *find* just to match files with an extension; you can use [shell globs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) instead to populate your loop constructs. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run sed on each file to delete the line.
for file in *txt; do
    sed -i '/text to match/d' "$file"
done
```

This is simple, and avoids a number of filename-related issues that you may have when passing filename arguments between processes. Keep it simple!

Comment: Or simply: sed -i '/text to match/d' \*.txt (for gnu-sed). or sed -i ""  '/text/d' \*.txt for portable sed. And for recursive (bash4) sed -i '/text/d' \**/\*.txt (KISS)

Answer (score 3):

Easy cheasy: 
`sed -i "s/^.*string.*//" *.txt`
this will remove any line containing 'string' on each .txt file

Comment: a.) The -i need an argument (for the backup extension) or empty if don't want backup, like -i "" . b.) s/.*someting.*// does _not_ delete the line, only replace it with the empty line. So it __is__ easy cheasy, but not your solution, but: sed -i "" "/string/d" *.txt

Comment: You sure are right about replacing instead of deleting, but not sure what you mean about the -i option. If the -i is empty, `sed -i "s/string/d" *.txt` works just fine, no need for the extra "" after -i

Comment: only on gnu-sed. portable sed must have the empty string "" for the simple overwrite without backup...

Answer (score 1):

You use it [along with `read`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to get each filename in turn, after piping the results of `find` to it. Then you just pass the filename to `sed` to delete the lines you're interested in.

Comment: you mean like this
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt | read
But how to reach each entry of read? can you explain a little more plz

Comment: "How should I use "while" to go through of each file?" Read the link.

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(file_listoflinks, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f_link:
    lines = f_link.readlines() # read an store all lines into list
    f_link.seek(0) # move file pointer to the beginning of a file
    f_link.truncate() # truncate the file
    # start writing lines except the first line
    # lines[1:] from line 2 to last line
    f_link.writelines(lines[1:])
```